# Why isn't enable_if working here?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code, my expectation is that there would be two different versions of operator `()` based on the type of the template parameter.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Impl
{
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value,T> operator()(const std::string& key, int node)
    {
        return static_cast<T>();
    }
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value,T> operator()(const std::string& key, int node)
    {
        return new T();
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Instead I get an error compiling:
`'std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value, T> Impl<T>::operator()(const string&, int)' cannot be overloaded with 'std::enable_if_t<(! std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value), T> Impl<T>::operator()(const string&, int)'`

Comment: Nit Pick: What is `static_cast<T>();`?

Comment: @WhiZTiM [ftfy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4418f30d119f86fe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `operator()` are not function templates themselves, so there is no context for SFINAE. Try this:

```
template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<U>::value,U> operator()(const std::string& key, int node)
{
    return static_cast<U>();
}

template <typename U = T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value,U> operator()(const std::string& key, int node)
{
    return new U();
}
```

Comment: While your answer is correct. `static_cast<U>();` is an invalid expression

Comment: What's `T` in your answer?

Comment: @NeomerArcana The same as in `template<typename T> struct Impl {...};`